# call php page before submiting to paypal

Tags: php, javascript, paypal-ipn

what am trying to do is , once a person click on paypal button, I hash his username and db from session and I save it to `Transactions` and send it as custom to paypal ,so when the payment is done I can get the transaction from db and complete the payment, but that is not working... here is the codes

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["logged"]))
{
    require_once ("config.php");
    if (isset($_POST["hsubmit"]))
    {
        $hashed = MD5($_SESSION["username"] . $_SESSION["db"] . time());
        mysql_query('INSERT INTO `Transactions` (trans_id,username,db) VALUES ( "' . $hashed .
            '" , "' . $_SESSION["username"] . '" , "' . $_SESSION["db"] . '" ) ') or die(mysql_error
            ());
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $hashed . '" />';
    }
    echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
function Check(){
        document.forms["_xclick"]["amount"].value = items[document.forms["_xclick"]["os0"].value];
        document.forms["_xclick"]["item_name"].value = document.forms["_xclick"]["os0"].value;
        document.forms["hide"].submit();

        return true;
    }
</script>
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="mail@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="index.php?page=paypal_ipn.php" />
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="UG Offers">UG Offers</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
        <script type="text/javascript"> var items = new Array(); </script>;';

    $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `purchasetypes`');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $row["name"] . '">  ' . $row["name"] . ' $' . $row["usd_price"] .
            ' USD</option>';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> items["' . $row["name"] . '"] = "' . $row["usd_price"] .
            '"; </script>';
    }
    echo '
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" onClick="Check();">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
<form id="hidden" name="hide" action="index.php?page=donate" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="hsubmit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
</form>
';
}

?>
```

Comment: Where is your `session_start()` on this page?

Comment: well I forgot to add it, but even when it's there same thing the page is not called!

Comment: No, please don't attempt this. For users who have javascript disabled, payment would still be possible, but it won't be sent to your server. You just need to change `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="paypal_ipn.php" />` into a public address paypal can understand.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="paypal_ipn.php" />` that is not the `url` that I use in real code , it's just to show u how am doing it, the real one looks like this `site.com/xxx/paypal_ipn.php`